# iOS y Plan Premium de Google Maps

Tags: ios

es posible usar la llave Premium de Google maps en una aplicación iOS sin necesidad de importar el SDK de Google Maps? O es necesario importar la SDK?

saludos

Comment: Hola Ojrzsr. Estás en el sitio en español, por lo que toda publicación debe ser en español. Si quieres que la pregunta esté en el sitio en inglés solamente, puedes reportar tu pregunta y solicitar una migración.

Answer (score 1):

Para utilizar los mapas de Google es necesario descargar el SDK si. Podes descargarlo utilizando cocoapods o directamente descargarlo de la pagina web e instalarlo.

Después de instalarlo tienes que solicitar un API key y agregarlo a la aplicación llamando al SDK desde el AppDelegate.

Puedes basarte en la guía oficial que te sera de mas utilidad: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

Answer (score 1):

debes importar el SDK de Google Maps, bien sea utilizando cocoa pods o descargándolo directamente.

Si vas a utilizar cocoapods, tienes que agregar en el archivo Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
target 'NOMBRE_TARGET' do
pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

En el AppDelegate se importa:

```
import GoogleMaps
import UIKit

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let googleMapsApiKey = "MY_GOOGLE_IOS_API_KEY"

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleMapsApiKey)
        return true
     }
}
```

En iOS, no puedes usar el **Id de Cliente**, solamente la **Clave de Api**.

"Puedes usar una clave de API para autenticar solicitudes a cualquiera de nuestras API. Para crear tu clave, deberás usar el proyecto de la Google API Console asociado con tu ID de proyecto.

En lugar de una clave de API, puedes usar tu ID de cliente para realizar solicitudes a cualquiera de las API, a **excepción** de la Google Places API, la Google Maps Geolocation API, la Google Maps Roads API y las **Mobile API (Android e iOS)**."
[Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview#client_id)